# Android list view - Human interface guidelines

Tags: android, android-listview, ui-guidelines

Is there any recommendation on how big each cell has to be in terms of dp in a listview. (Assume a list view with just one line of text)?

Thanks, 
Teja

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if "how big each cell" means row height then

android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"

should help

Answer (score 4):

Addition to Selvin's answer.

If you want it from source code:

```
R.attr.listPreferredItemHeight
```

Answer (score 0):

Via Code:

R.attr.listPreferredItemHeight is only the resource id and not the value.

this works: [Android: how to get value of "listPreferredItemHeight" attribute in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982132/android-how-to-get-value-of-listpreferreditemheight-attribute-in-code)