# Android: how to get value of "listPreferredItemHeight" attribute in code?

Tags: android

The below code gives `Resources$NotFoundException`

```
TypedValue value = new TypedValue();
((Activity)context).getResources().getValue(android.R.attr.listPreferredItemHeight, value, true);
```

EDIT: More code added in response to answer.

When I run the below code, all members of `displayMetrics` are 0.  As is `ret`.

```
TypedValue value = new TypedValue();
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
((Activity)context).getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.listPreferredItemHeight, value, true);
float ret = value.getDimension(displayMetrics);
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This works:

```
TypedValue value = new TypedValue();
((Activity)context).getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.listPreferredItemHeight, value, true);
```

EDIT: You get zero because haven't initialized the `DisplayMetrics` instance properly. It needs a frame of reference (a display) to do any meaningful conversion.

```
android.util.TypedValue value = new android.util.TypedValue();
boolean b = getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.listPreferredItemHeight, value, true);
String s = TypedValue.coerceToString(value.type, value.data);
android.util.DisplayMetrics metrics = new android.util.DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
float ret = value.getDimension(metrics);
```

On my Nexus 1 `s` is *64.0dip* and `ret` is *96*.

Comment: Thank you, this does not give an exception.  However, I still can't get the value of the attribute.  I updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: how do I get int of value 64 from TypedValue? I can't find a way to do that except parsing String from coerceToString.

Comment: Ah, found it! TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(value.data, metrics)

Comment: How can you parse the attribute from an extended class like `LinearLayout`? It seems I don't have access to `getTheme()` and trying `context.getResources().getValue(R.styleable.my_attr, value, true);` throws a `ResourcesNotFound`

Comment: Note that in the above, this is called from the constructor `public Foo(Context context, AttributeSet attr)`

Comment: An easier way to get display metrics if you have a context or are inside a fragment is by doing: `getResources().getDisplayMetrics()` or  `Context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics()`

Answer (score 10):

Another answer

```
public float getItemHeight() {
    TypedValue value = new TypedValue();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();

    context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(
            android.R.attr.listPreferredItemHeight, value, true);
    ((WindowManager) (context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)))
            .getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    return TypedValue.complexToDimension(value.data, metrics);
}
```

it maybe more useful.

Answer (score 8):

Femi's answer was very helpful. Without wanting to detract from his answer, I've taken the logic and placed it in a [library convenience method](https://svn.globalmentor.com/java/trunk/globalmentor-android/src/main/java/com/globalmentor/android/content/res/Themes.java) that you should be able to plug-and-play. I plan on updating the code with other attribute methods over time. I hope it proves useful to someone.

(Note that I discovered `Resources.getDisplayMetrics()` seems to be an easier way to return display metrics rather than querying the WindowManager.)

Comment: I found only Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics(); for current Android version (4.4).

Answer (score 2):

The shortest answer <strike>(without `DisplayMetrics`)</strike>:

```
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.listPreferredItemHeight, typedValue, true);
int height = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(typedValue.data, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Comment: What happens if u remove the android prefix `resolveAttribute(R.attr.listPreferredItemHeight, typedValue, true);`?