# Android: Prevent different spinner heights (empty and filled)

Tags: android, layout, spinner, adapter, loader

I have some spinners on the layout and use loader to load their data from db in background. The problems is that empty spinners have smaller height until the data are loaded. So the layout jump.

How can I prevent this jumping?

**Edit (added spinner row layouts)**

Spinner row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/Text1"
        style="@style/StyleSpinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Spinner drop down row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/style_spinner_row_padding" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Text1"
        style="@style/StyleSpinnerDropDownRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Text2"
        style="@style/StyleSpinnerDropDownRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Text1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Assigned styles:

```
<!-- // Spinner // -->
<style name="StyleSpinner" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">start</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/default_text_size_normal</item>
    <item name="android:padding">@dimen/style_spinner_row_padding</item>
</style>

<style name="StyleSpinnerDropDownRow1" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/default_text_size_normal</item>
</style>

<style name="StyleSpinnerDropDownRow2" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/default_text_size_small</item>
</style>
```

Screen shots:

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can use an image which looks like drop down and set it as background of every spinner. Please let me know if that works. If possible then please go through the link http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/ and place an empty spinner there. You can see no fluctuation of height is occurring there.

Comment: I use the standard way of spinners (like in the tuturial) but with cursor (database data). And I use two own layout for spinner and drop down (I added the XML to the description).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just had this same issue and managed to fix it for myself so here's what I did.

I am inflating **android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item** in my spinner adapter for each item layout. When I looked at this layout I noticed it had no margins but just a set height which was coming from **android:attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight**.

So I thought I'd get this list preferred item height value programatically and set it as my spinners minimum height. Using the answer to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982132/android-how-to-get-value-of-listpreferreditemheight-attribute-in-code) I was able to get the correct value and set it to my spinner.

```
    android.util.TypedValue value = new android.util.TypedValue();
    getActivity().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.listPreferredItemHeight, value, true);
    android.util.DisplayMetrics metrics = new android.util.DisplayMetrics();
    getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    float ret = value.getDimension(metrics);

    mSpinner.setMinimumHeight((int) (ret - 1 * metrics.density));
```

I've removed 1dip because it seems that the returned value has been rounded up which makes it 1 pixel too high.

Now all my spinner are the same height, whether they have items or are empty.

Comment: This works perfectly and build the basis for my own minHeight calculation. I reduce the spinner height for small screen sizes.

`float reduce = context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.style_spinner_reduced_height);
    float ret = value.getDimension(metrics);

    spinner.setMinimumHeight((int) (ret - reduce - 1 * metrics.density));`

The default value for reduce is 12dp for me.

Comment: Tried this, but the minimum height seems to be a lot bigger than the height when this code was not applied and the spinner was filled with real items.

Comment: to anyone who wants to use this on xml can use like this android:layout_height="?attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the heights changing from when I load it in the background I just created a none array and in the xml set the entries to it:

In array.xml

```
 <string-array name="none">
        <item></item>
 </string-array>
```

In the spinners

```
android:entries:@array/none
```

The heights do not change because once the loader finishes it replaces the contents of the spinner anyway.

Comment: I will try this solution too. It sounds like a very handy and simple workaround for me.

Comment: Didn't work. Also, it showed an empty item when clicked before the spinner was updated with real items.

Answer (score -1):

I used an `arrayAdapter<String>` with an empty array.

After you have got what you need just get a new adapter or use the same adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.